# Intermittence when trying to create Orchestrator Snapshot

Tags: botframework

Most of half of the tries when running the comman `bf orchestrator:create`, the output given is the error:

```
2021-07-14 17:28:36.3948734 [E:onnxruntime:, inference_session.cc:1294 onnxruntime::InferenceSession::Initialize::<lambda_14ab80433efd07306ceb190544d07c3a>::operator ()] Exception during initialization: bad allocation
EXCEPTION THROWN - utility_onnx::OnnxUtility::InitOnnxSession(): e.what()=Exception during initialization: bad allocation, __FILE__=D:\a\1\s\oc\utility\OnnxUtility.h, __LINE__=117
EXCEPTION THROWN - OC - EmbedderBase::EmbedderBase(json const& config, const string onnxVocabFileDefault, const string onnxModelFileDefault): e.what()=Exception during initialization: bad allocation, FILE=D:\a\1\s\oc\EmbedderBase.cc, LINE=57
Exception during initialization: bad allocation
```

List of Commands that I ran:

> ```
> bf orchestrator:add -t qna --id "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" -k "xxxx" --routingName "q_xxxx"
>
> bf orchestrator:basemodel:get --out model
>
> bf orchestrator:create --model model --out generated
> ```

Could you please help me to identify the root cause?

Comment: You can refer to https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-cli/issues/1275 for more details on how to resolve the issue.